# vis.timeline is not getting rendered in IE9

Tags: javascript, chap-links-library, vis.js

I created a timeline chart using vis.js timeline, It is getting rendered properly in chrome but not in IE9. Does vis.js has support for IE9?

Comment: Normally looking at the docs would be the best way to go, but its really bad and they don't mention support. So i checked out the examples and the source code (breifly), theres nothing there that would suggest that it can't work in IE9....

Comment: Are there any errors in the console when you have it open in IE9?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem with latest vis.js (4.3.0)
After some investigation, I found that I had asked for IE 8 compatibility in my html page (meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"): removing this meta tag made vis.js work smoothly in my IE 9